# How can i fix on APL2 the generated error code AP211-10

Tags: host, mainframe

A procedure on APL2 returns the error AP211-10 when it tries to execute a sentence VLIST. When it writes the file, it seems not to have enough space. Where do we have to change the parameter?

In the IBM doc AP211-10 means a problem in I/O file. And it seems related with the common error B37.

The expected result is the creation of the file correctly but actually the file created is corrupted and it is not possible to open on APL2.

Comment: Are you using JCL to run the program?   A B37 is a an out of space or extents error that can be fixed by changing your Job's SPACE parameter ... if you're using one.

Comment: Thanks Jim! In the APL2 platform, we don't select the SPACE as in JCLs. It is parametrized but I don't know where, this is my real question. Where can I change the values of parametres?

Comment: Default parameter settings are usually managed by your system programming staff, who should also be the ones who installed it. There might be some usable information in [here](https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/0KMVLAQ1), that could help you figure out which file needs to be updated. The main APL2 manual page is [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/apilite?infotype=PM%20OR%20SA&lastdays=4055&appname=apl2&doctype=PL2GNRLI%20or%20PL2MFRAM%20or%20PL2WRKST).